# Power Distribution

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, camera, teensy, power-divider

I work on a project that need a power distribution method. I thought some schematic bellow that you can see. I don't try that connections because I am not sure. If anyone can warn me about my mistakes I will really gratefull for that.

Datasheets:

Regulator: https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/l78-974043.pdf

FPV Camera:
https://www.urhanshop.com/eachine-tx03-ntsc-025mw50mw--200mw-degistirilebilir-aio-58g-72ch-vtx-600tvl-13-cmos-fpv-kamera-u18828?gclid=CjwKCAjw_YShBhAiEiwAMomsEOqI9ii_HU0ds0nfSVqK4Y96EbhQb6iimN0yybcCzJb5e5qll017ihoCsTQQAvD_BwE

[image]

Comment: I don't find `7-13V Supply voltage` for the camera, but much lower values - including what I find for the Teensy 3.5. Please include in the question the specifications you are working from.

Answer (score 0):

the regulator L7805 is a three terminal positive voltage regulator, it can provide output current up to 1.5 A. You also should add some filter capacitors in the input and the output of the IC.

The datasheet for the camera shows an input of [2.5V-5.5V] is recommended using a 1S Lipo Battery [3.7-4.2V]

The Teensy3.5 Vin=[3.6V-6V] so I think you should increase capacity of the battery pack and lower the Voltage since its not needed and keep the regulator for stabilizations.
[image]

[image]

Also don't forget to protect your battery pack using a 2S BMS.

[image]

Comment: The 3.6V-6V for the Teensy 3.5 is here https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy35.html but usually using a 5V is sufficient since its the voltage used by USB.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your return. The supply voltage of the camera is between 7-13V. The link I sent was wrong, you need to look at it according to the schematic I drew. Also, as you can see in the schematic, there is a parallelism to the camera with one arm, the other arm being 5V regulator and teensy. Will this pose any problem?

Comment: @TA2ERR You can't exceed 13V with the camera then. Would you mind sharing more informations about what are you trying to achieve and the correct datasheets.